# next/prev post link by relationship post 2 post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I have a CPT called Movies and Episode List. I create a movie called "Paranormal Activity" and I create "episode 1", "episode 2", "episode 3", "episode 4". I connect each of them to "Paranormal Activity" with plugin **post 2 posts** by scribu. I have follow the tutorials here [posts 2 posts support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_related-only-next-and-previous-post?replies=20)
its still don't work.

[image]

It's shown at http://localhost/movie/conor ( what I called "Paranormal Activity") and this is the code what I have tested:

```
$episode_id = get_the_ID();

$prev = p2p_type( 'posts_to_pages' )->get_adjacent_items( $episode_id );

$next = p2p_type( 'posts_to_pages' )->get_adjacent_items( $movie_id, $episode_id );

$items = p2p_type( 'posts_to_pages' )->get_adjacent_items( $episode_id );

echo get_permalink( $items['parent'] );

if ( $items['previous'] )
 echo 'previous: ' . get_permalink( $items['previous'] );

if ( $items['next'] )
 echo 'next: ' . get_permalink( $items['next'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
$connection_type = 'posts_to_pages';
$items = p2p_type($connection_type)->get_adjacent_items( $episode_id );

if ( $items['previous'] )
  echo get_permalink($items['previous']->ID);
```

Comment: Please don´t just post code, explain what it does and why it works.